# How can I rotate and scale a texture in cycles?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

When I try to rotate and scale the texture in the mapping node it only changes the color of the texture.How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're providing image texture as a vector coordinates for the mapping node, it won't work correctly.

Comment: The right order for the nodes is Texture Coordinates->Mapping->Image Texture->Shader Color

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch the order of the nodes. "Texture mapping" needs to go before "image texture"